# How to add MKMapView to tableView.BackgroundView with constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mkmapview, tableview

Im adding a MKMapView to my tableview background in ViewdidLoad simply like this and its working.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var myMapView = MKMapView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 500))
    myMapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard

    self.tableView.backgroundView? = myMapView


}
```

This displays the map view in the background of the tableview but I wish for the MapView to only be displayed on the bottom of the tableview background and with the height of 250

Im guessing you have to add it as a subview and add constraints, could somebody show me some code as to how they would go about this?

Thanks!